# How to extract text from a tag containing pseudo-element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a website, I want to extract only the location (text) from a span tag containing a pseudo-element (::after) within other parent div tags thus:

[image: website snippet]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re    
url = 'https://some website'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
locations = soup.find_all("span", class_=re.compile("text$"))
for location in locations:
    print(location.text)
```

I also think that not all the div tags contain the tag for location. It's not giving any output and not returning any error.
But expected output for example will be 'Lagos,Lekki' amidst others. Any method is appreciated.

Comment: Question needs some more info to clarify  - Check your `soup` if element you are looking for is available , not the rendered source from browser.

Comment: And what would be the url of the page you're trying to scrape? Is it a well guarded secret?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus No it's not, I just thought it won't be needed to solve the issue, so no need to paste it; but this is the url: 'https://jiji.ng/mobile-phones'

Comment: @HedgeHog When I checked if the span element was available it returned <span class="fw-button__content"><!-- --> <span class="fw-button__slot-wrapper"><div class="fw-search__icon"><svg class="icon sprite-icons" color="#00B53F" height="24px" width="24px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="/_nuxt/881a923cbeb7acb3dc4acd9d412424fe.svg#i-search" xlink:href="/_nuxt/881a923cbeb7acb3dc4acd9d412424fe.svg#i-search"></use></svg></div></span></span>

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, content is loaded from additional request and rendered dynamically by browser. An alternative of using api, what I would recommend, could be selenium, etc. that act like a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is loaded via an additional api call and than rendered by the browser, a behavior what is not supported directly via `requests`. While the  content is not available in the response data `BeautifulSoup` is also not able to find it.

To get the data call the api directly and use the JSON repsonse to pick Information is needed.

##### Example

```
import requests
# list to hold all results
data = []

# for multiple pages iterate in range from - to
for i in range(0,2):
  # increase page by number of iteration
  url = f'https://jiji.ng/api_web/v1/listing?slug=mobile-phones&init_page=true&page={i}'
  # extend list with all items per page
  data.extend(requests.get(url).json()['adverts_list']['adverts'])

for item in data:
  print(item.get('region_item_text'))
```

##### Output

```
Lagos, Lekki
Lagos, Lekki
Lagos, Ikeja
Lagos, Ikeja
Lagos, Ikeja
Oyo, Ibadan
Oyo, Ibadan
Abuja, Kubwa
Imo, Owerri
Lagos, Ikeja
Oyo, Oyo / Oyo State
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how do I know contents that are loaded by additional api call for future purposes?

Comment: First of all, check the response to the request or the soup to see if the expected content can be found there. If not, take a look at your browser's developer tools and examine the XHR requests tab to get a good start. Everything else is a matter of practice and experience.

Comment: One more thing, please could you explain the code? I don't understand especially the first for loop.

Comment: I've been trying to convert the output to a python list to no avail. Please could you help out?

Comment: `data` is already a `list` that contains all the contents, so it would be best practice to use this one and transform it into dataframe, csv, ...- Maybe this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and some more details about expected goal. Simply drop the link to the new questin here, so everybody could take a look.

Comment: Here is the link to the another question: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75606636/how-to-access-a-list-of-dictionaries-containing-lists-of-dictionaries-and-nested'